# Combine data frame rows and keep certain values

Tags: python

I have the following dataset:

This data set can contain multiple entries for one person.

| Name | Year | Attempt | Math | English | Science | Height | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 2020 | 1 | 92 | 95 | 82 | 63 | Top 50 |
| Peter | 2021 | 2 | 93 | 94 | 86 | 63 | Top 50 |
| Andy | 2023 | 1 | 84 | 91 | 87 | 68 | 51-100 |
| Charles | 2019 | 1 | 87 | 89 | 82 | 67 | 101-150 |
| Charles | 2020 | 2 | 92 | 91 | 76 | 67 | 101-150 |
| Charles | 2021 | 3 | 94 | 92 | 90 | 67 | 101-150 |
| Charles | 2022 | 4 | 87 | 98 | 99 | 67 | 101-150 |
| Luke | 2023 | 1 | 76 | 98 | 99 | 80 | Unranked |

I want to manipulate the data frame to look like this:

| Name | Final Year | Attempt | Math | English | Science | Height | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 2021 | [1, 2] | [92, 93] | [95, 94] | [82, 86] | 63 | Top 50 |
| Andy | 2023 | 1 | 84 | 91 | 87 | 68 | 51-100 |
| Charles | 2022 | [1, 2, 3, 4] | [87, 92, 94, 87] | [89, 91, 92, 98] | [82, 76, 90, 99] | 67 | 101-150 |
| Luke | 2023 | 1 | 76 | 98 | 99 | 80 | Unranked |

columns Height and Rank will always be the same across multiple entires. I want the latest year in the Final Year column.

```
df2 = (df.set_index('Name').groupby(level = 0).agg(list))
df2['Age'] = df2['Age'].apply(max)
df2[['Height', 'Rank']]  = df2[['Height', 'Rank']].apply(lambda x: x[0])
display(df2)
```

| Name | Year | Attempt | Math | English | Science | Height | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 2021 | [2, 1] | [93, 92] | [94, 95] | [86, 82] | NA | NA |
| Andy | 2023 | 1 | 84 | 91 | 87 | NA | NA |
| Charles | 2022 | [4, 3, 2, 1] | [87, 94, 92, 87] | [98, 92, 91, 89] | [99, 90, 76, 82] | NA | NA |
| Luke | 2023 | 1 | 76 | 98 | 99 | NA | NA |

columns Attempt, Math, English are printing in reverse order. I am attempting to get the first value in the list in columns Height and Rank but the columns are populated with NA.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframe `agg` method can take a dictionary which maps column names to functions, as can be seen in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html#:%7E:text=dict%20of%20axis%20labels%20%2D%3E%20functions%2C%20function%20names%20or%20list%20of%20such.).

```py
aggs = {_: list for _ in ["Attempt", "Math", "English", "Science"]}
aggs["Age"] = "max"
aggs["Height"] = "first"
aggs["Rank"] = "first"

df2 = (
    df
    .set_index('Name')
    .groupby(level = 0)
    .agg(aggs)
)
```